# Constructive proof of the approximate Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem for $\Delta^n$

Tags: reference-request, fixed-point-theorems, constructive-mathematics

The approximate Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem (**aBFPT**) for the standard $n$-simplex is:

> Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous function from $\Delta^n$ into itself.
>   Then for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x\in\Delta^n$ such that
>   $d(f(x),x)<\varepsilon$.

Does anyone know a reference for a full proof of **aBFPT** via Sperner's Lemma in [Bishop-style](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642649059) constructive mathematics (**BISH**)?

A constructive proof of **aBFPT** via [Gale's](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~gartside/hex_Browuer.pdf) Hex Theorem is in Hendtlass's [PhD thesis](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/19417936.pdf). A constructive proof for the $2$-simplex is in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397511002787?via%3Dihub) by van Dalen. That's all I could find.

If you don't know a reference but have a proof handy I'd very much like to see that as well.

Thank you in advance!

Note: The status of **BFPT** in constructive mathematics has been discussed in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202811/does-the-brouwer-fixed-point-theorem-admit-a-constructive-proof). For quick orientation: **aBFPT** may be viewed as constituting the constructive core of the full classical **BFPT**. The latter implies **LLPO** and is thus inherently nonconstructive (indeed, the two are equivalent over **BISH** since both are equivalent to **WKL** in the presence of countable choice). Classically, **BFPT** can be retrieved from **aBFPT** by a simple application of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, which is equivalent to **LPO** over **BISH** and thus constructively inadmissible.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you might want to look in the computational complexity literature.  Approximate Brouwer is an exemplar of a complexity class that has turned out to be interesting, called PPAD.

Comment: I am not proficient at all in this topic. But I do know about two papers of Orevkov that might be relevant here ( http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tm&paperid=1617&option_lang=eng and http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tm&paperid=2831&option_lang=eng ). As far as I understand, he studied Brower's Fixed Point theorem in the context of Russian constructive mathematics. In particular, Theorem 7.1 from the second paper is aBFPT. Unfortunately, both the papers are in Russian and they seems not to be translated in English.

Comment: I just found out that actually there exist an English translation of the second paper. It is in the volume "Problems in the Constructive Trend in Mathematics, IV" that were translated in English.

Comment: All van Dalen does is taking the usual argument based on Sperner's lemma and getting rid of having to decide ordering relations by adding some additional slack. The same method works for the usual arguments and does not depend on the dimension being 2.

Comment: There are also seems to be an explicit prove for the general case in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4020-8926-8_14